# solve quadratic inequality for all cases

Tags: inequality, quadratics

I am in great danger. I am solving a general quadratic inequality $ax^2+bx+c \ge 0$ for $a \neq 0$ as follows:

Let $$ax^2 +bx+c = 0,$$ then the critical points are: $$x= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ Then we have three intervals $$\left(- \infty, \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right], \left[\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \infty\right), \text{ and } \left[ \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},  \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right].$$

I know that since the inequality is greater than 0, the first two will satisfy the inequality. Hence $$ \left(- \infty, \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right] \cup \left[\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \infty\right)$$ is the solution of the given quadratic inequality.

My professor keeps saying "you are wrong, answer me completely and accurately". Anyone, please help me what I am missing and what should be the correct answer?

Comment: This is correct only when a>0.

Comment: You need to consider the fact that $a<0$ is possible. Moreover, you need to separate the cases where the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ is greater than zero, equal to zero and less than zero (for instance, the intervals you write don't make sense in the case that $\Delta<0$).

Comment: As a rule, you can make this less unwieldy by setting $r_1,r_2$ to the two roots, rather than constantly repeating those quadratic formulae.

Comment: By the way, a “critical point” has a definition. These aren’t critical points. They are just important points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)

Comment: What you are being asked is equivalent to the question: for what $ \ x-$ coordinates of its points is a parabola above or on the $ \ x-$ axis?  Must the answer always be _two_ intervals? Could the answer just be _a single point?_  _Must_ the inequality _always_ have a solution? [Picture the various possibilities.]

Comment: Check the [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133368/systematically-solving-ax2bxc0-and-the-like?rq=1).

Comment: You can separate it into three parts: when the quadratic has no real roots, a (repeated) real root, and two distinct real roots. Then, work for $a>0$ and $a<0$ for each case. What you do is essentially just one part of the total six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is nothing more than a consolidation of all of the responses.

To solve: $ax^2 + bx + c \geq 0.$

Since it is presumed that $a \neq 0$, the first thing to do is to break the analysis into two cases: $a < 0$ or $a > 0$.  Then, similar to the manner of deriving the quadratic equation, in each case, you must *complete* the square.

In both cases, I will use the observation that 
$x^2 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)x = \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}.$

I will also use the observation that when $r,s \geq 0$, you have that 
$(r \geq s) \iff (r^2 \geq s^2).$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~a > 0}$

Then $x^2 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)x + \frac{c}{a} \geq 0.$

Therefore $\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a} \geq 0.$

Therefore

$$\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 \geq \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}.\tag1$$

Within Case 1: there are therefore two possibilities:

Case 1A:
$b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$.

In this event, based on inequality (1) above, then $x$ must satisfy: 
$\left|x + \frac{b}{2a}\right| \geq \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

This is satisfied when 
$x \leq - \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right) - \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ 
**or** 
$x \geq - \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

Case 1B:
$b^2 - 4ac < 0$.

Examining inequality (1) above, since case 1B is presuming that the RHS $< 0$, and since the LHS is always non-negative, inequality (1) will be satisfied for **any** value of $x$.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~a < 0}$

Then $x^2 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)x + \frac{c}{a} \leq 0.$

Therefore $\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a} \leq 0.$

Therefore

$$\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 \leq \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}.\tag2$$

Case 2A:
$b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$.

In this event, based on inequality (2) above, then $x$ must satisfy: 
$\left|x + \frac{b}{2a}\right| \leq \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{|2a|}$.

This is satisfied when 
$x \geq - \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right) - \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{|2a|}$ 
**and** 
$x \leq - \left(\frac{b}{2a}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{|2a|}$.

Case 2B:
$b^2 - 4ac < 0$.

Examining inequality (2) above, since case 2B is presuming that the RHS $< 0$, and since the LHS is always non-negative, inequality (2) will **never** be satisfied for **any** value of $x$.

Comment: (+1) Amazing summary. Another way of looking at case 1B and 2B is, if $D<0$, then quadratic has no roots so it is either all above the x-axis ($a>0$) or all below the x-axis ($a<0$).